# How to save the progress of this game

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, save

So me and my friend are making this game and we want it to save how many coins, machines, drills, etc. you have before closing the page that way when you come back you aren't at rock bottom again. This is my first time doing anything like this and ChatGPT recommends using cookies. I've looked it up and it doesn't make much sense to me. Can someone explain and/or give me the code that I need for it?
(P.S. I'm using Glitch.com. Not sure if you needed to know that or not.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>MinerTest</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var coins = 100;
      var workers = 0;
      var cost = 50;
      var machinesCost = 10000;
      var machines = 0;
      var machinesFactor = 1.1;
      var dynamiteCost = 50000;
      var dynamite = 0;
      var dynamiteFactor = 1.15;
      var drillsCost = 125000;
      var drills = 0;
      var drillsFactor = 1.15;
      var dupesCost = 2000000;
      var dupes = 0;
      var dupesFactor = 1.2;
      var cworkersCost = 5000000;
      var cworkers = 0;
      var cworkersFactor = 1.15;
      var crystals = 0;
      function clickCoin() {
        coins++;
        updateCoins();
      }


      // Load game data if it exists
  if (localStorage.getItem("minerGameData") !== null) {
    var savedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("minerGameData"));
    coins = savedData.coins;
    workers = savedData.workers;
    cost = savedData.cost;
    machinesCost = savedData.machinesCost;
    machines = savedData.machines;
    machinesFactor = savedData.machinesFactor;
    dynamiteCost = savedData.dynamiteCost;
    dynamite = savedData.dynamite;
    dynamiteFactor = savedData.dynamiteFactor;
    drillsCost = savedData.drillsCost;
    drills = savedData.drills;
    drillsFactor = savedData.drillsFactor;
    dupesCost = savedData.dupesCost;
    dupes = savedData.dupes;
    dupesFactor = savedData.dupesFactor;
    cworkersCost = savedData.cworkersCost;
    cworkers = savedData.cworkers;
    cworkersFactor = savedData.cworkersFactor;
    crystals = savedData.crystals;
    updateCoins();
  }
  
  function clickCoin() {
    coins++;
    updateCoins();
    saveGameData();
  }

  function hireWorker() {
    if (coins < cost) {
      document.getElementById("workerError").innerHTML =
        "Not enough coins :(";
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("workerError").innerHTML = "";
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      coins -= cost;
      workers++;
      updateCoins();
      updateCost();
      if (workers == 10) {
        document.getElementById("machines").style.display = "block";
      }
      setInterval(function () {
        coins += 20;
        updateCoins();
      }, 1000);
      saveGameData();
    }
  }
  
  function hireCworker() {
    if (coins < cworkersCost) {
      document.getElementById("cworkerError").innerHTML =
        "Not enough coins :(";
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("cworkerError").innerHTML = "";
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      coins -= cworkersCost;
      cworkers++;
      updateCoins();
      updateCost();
      setInterval(function () {
        crystals += 5;
        updateCrystals();
      }, 1000);
      saveGameData();
    }
  }

  function buyMachines() {
    if (coins < machinesCost) {
      document.getElementById("machinesError").innerHTML =
        "Not enough coins :(";
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("machinesError").innerHTML = "";
          }, 3000);
        } else {
          coins -= machinesCost;
          machines++;
          updateCoins();
          updateMachinesCost();
          if (machines == 20) {
            document.getElementById("dynamite").style.display = "block";
          }
          setInterval(function () {
            coins += 200;
            updateCoins();
          }, 500);
        }
      }

      function buyDynamite() {
        if (coins < dynamiteCost) {
          document.getElementById("dynamiteError").innerHTML =
            "Not enough coins :(";
          setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("dynamiteError").innerHTML = "";
          }, 3000);
        } else {
          coins -= dynamiteCost;
          dynamite++;
          updateCoins();
          updateDynamiteCost();
          if (dynamite == 50) {
            document.getElementById("drills").style.display = "block";
          }
          setInterval(function () {
            coins += 500;
            updateCoins();
          }, 1000);
        }
      }

      function buyDrills() {
        if (coins < drillsCost) {
          document.getElementById("drillsError").innerHTML =
            "Not enough coins :(";
          setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("drillsError").innerHTML = "";
          }, 3000);
        } else {
          coins -= drillsCost;
          drills++;
          updateCoins();
          updateDrillsCost();
          if (drills == 100) {
            document.getElementById("dupes").style.display = "block";
          }
          setInterval(function () {
            coins += 5000;
            updateCoins();
          }, 1000);
        }
      }

      function buyDupes() {
        if (coins < dupesCost) {
          document.getElementById("dupesError").innerHTML =
            "Not enough coins :(";
          setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("dupesError").innerHTML = "";
          }, 3000);
        } else {
          coins -= dupesCost;
          dupes++;
          updateCoins();
          updateDupesCost();
          setInterval(function () {
            coins += 20000;
            updateCoins();
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
 


     function updateCoins() {
  document.getElementById("coinCount").innerHTML = coins.toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById("workerCount").innerHTML = workers;
  document.getElementById("machinesCount").innerHTML = machines;
  document.getElementById("dynamiteCount").innerHTML = dynamite;
  document.getElementById("drillsCount").innerHTML = drills;
  document.getElementById("dupesCount").innerHTML = dupes;
  document.getElementById("cworkerCount").innerHTML = cworkers;
  document.getElementById("crystalsCount").innerHTML = crystals.toFixed(0);
}

      function updateCrystals() {
        document.getElementById("crystalsCount").innerHTML =
          crystals.toFixed(0);
        document.getElementById("cworkerCount").innerHTML = cworkers;
      }

      function updateCost() {
        cost = cost * 1.35;
        document.getElementById("workerCost").innerHTML = cost.toFixed(0);
      }

      function updateMachinesCost() {
        machinesCost = machinesCost * machinesFactor;
        document.getElementById("machinesCost").innerHTML =
          machinesCost.toFixed(0);
      }

      function updateDynamiteCost() {
        dynamiteCost = dynamiteCost * dynamiteFactor;
        document.getElementById("dynamiteCost").innerHTML =
          dynamiteCost.toFixed(0);
      }
      function updateDrillsCost() {
        drillsCost = drillsCost * drillsFactor;
        document.getElementById("drillsCost").innerHTML = drillsCost.toFixed(0);
      }
      function updateDupesCost() {
        dupesCost = dupesCost * dupesFactor;
        document.getElementById("dupesCost").innerHTML = dupesCost.toFixed(0);
      }
      function updateCworkerCost() {
        cworkerCost = cworkerCost * cworkerFactor;
        document.getElementById("cworkerCost").innerHTML =
          cworkerCost.toFixed(0);
      }

      function boostCoins() {
        if (crystals < 100) {
          document.getElementById("boostError").innerHTML =
            "Not enough crystals :(";
          setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("boostError").innerHTML = "";
          }, 3000);
        } else {
          coins -= 1000000;
          setInterval(function () {
            coins += 50000;
            updateCoins();
          }, 1000);
        }
      }

      function boostCrystals() {
        if (crystals < 1000) {
          document.getElementById("cboostError").innerHTML =
            "Not enough crystals :(";
          setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("cboostError").innerHTML = "";
          }, 3000);
        } else {
          crystals -= 1000;
          setInterval(function () {
            crystals += 50000;
            crystals();
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
      function openTab(evt, tabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
      }
      const otherTabLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-link:not(#settings-tab-link)");

// Calculate the time spent on the site
var startTime = Date.now();

function updateTimeSpent() {
  var timeDiff = Date.now() - startTime;
  var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

  // Format the time display
  var timeDisplay = "";
  if (days > 0) {
    timeDisplay += days + " days ";
  }
  if (hours > 0) {
    timeDisplay += (hours % 24) + " hours ";
  }
  if (minutes > 0) {
    timeDisplay += (minutes % 60) + " minutes ";
  }
  if (seconds > 0) {
    timeDisplay += (seconds % 60) + " seconds";
  }

  // Update the time display element
  document.getElementById("time-spent").innerHTML = timeDisplay;
}

// Update the time display every second
setInterval(updateTimeSpent, 1000);

// Retrieve the most coins earned from local storage
var mostCoins = localStorage.getItem("mostCoins");
if (!mostCoins) {
  mostCoins = 0;
}

// Update the most coins display element
document.getElementById("most-coins").innerHTML = mostCoins;

      // Get the color picker input and the apply color button
const colorPicker = document.querySelector('#color-picker');
const applyColorBtn = document.querySelector('#apply-color');

// Add a click event listener to the apply color button
applyColorBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Get the value of the color picker
  const selectedColor = colorPicker.value;

  // Change the background color of the website
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
});

      document.getElementById("reset-progress-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Code to reset progress goes here
});

      document.cookie = "progress=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";

     

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
          body {
             width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
            background-color: #000000;
            color: #FFA500;
            text-align: center;
          }
                  button {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: orange;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: 1px solid;
        border: none;
      }
      button:hover {
        background-color: #4f4f4f;
      }
            .tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: none;
        background-color: black;
      }

      .tab button {
        background-color: black;
        border: none;
        outline: solid, pink;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .tab button:hover {
        background-color: grey;
      }

      .tab button.active {
        background-color: grey;
      }

      .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px
          
          #font-changer {
  display: none;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>MinerTest</h1>
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab1')">
        Building 1
      </button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab2')">
        Building 2
      </button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab3')">
        Upgrades
      </button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab4')">Settings
        
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="Tab0" class="tabcontent">
      <p>
        Hi! Thank you for playing. We're just a couple of teenagers who got
        bored one day. To start click building 1 and start mining away. Can you
        be one of the greats?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Tab1" class="tabcontent">
      <p>
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/5aa86343-095b-4e79-b6a7-c5aa1a0f4506/coins-xxl.png?v=1679590249297"
          height="20"
        />
        <span id="coinCount">100</span>
      </p>
      <p>Workers: <span id="workerCount">0 :(</span></p>
      <p>Worker Cost: <span id="workerCost">50</span></p>
      <button onclick="hireWorker()">Hire Worker</button>
      <div id="workerError" style="color: red"></div>
      <div id="machines" style="display: none">
        <p>Machines: <span id="machinesCount">0 :(</span></p>
        <p>Machines Cost: <span id="machinesCost">10000</span></p>
        <button onclick="buyMachines()">Buy Machines</button>
        <div id="machinesError" style="color: red"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="dynamite" style="display: none">
        <p>Dynamite: <span id="dynamiteCount">0 :(</span></p>
        <p>Dynamite Cost: <span id="dynamiteCost">50000</span></p>
        <button onclick="buyDynamite()">Buy Dynamite</button>
        <div id="dynamiteError" style="color: red"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="drills" style="display: none">
        <p>Drills: <span id="drillsCount">0 :(</span></p>
        <p>Drills Cost: <span id="drillsCost">125000</span></p>
        <button onclick="buyDrills()">Buy Drills</button>
        <div id="dynamiteError" style="color: red"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="dupes" style="display: none">
        <p>Dupe Devices: <span id="dupesCount">0 :(</span></p>
        <p>Dupe Devices Cost: <span id="dupesCost">2000000</span></p>
        <button onclick="buyDupes()">Buy Dupe Devices</button>
        <div id="dupesError" style="color: red"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Tab2" class="tabcontent">
      <p>
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/5aa86343-095b-4e79-b6a7-c5aa1a0f4506/diamond-xxl.png?v=1679594976556"
          height="20"
        />
        <span id="crystalsCount">0</span>
      </p>
      <p>Crystal Workers: <span id="cworkerCount">0 :(</span></p>
      <p>Crystal Workers Cost: <span id="cworkerCost">5000000</span></p>
      <button onclick="hireCworker()">Hire Crystal Worker</button>
      <div id="cworkerError" style="color: red"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Tab3" class="tabcontent">
      <p>Coin Boost (Crystals) = 100</p>
      <button onclick="boostCoins()">Coin Booster</button>
      <div id="boostError" style="color: red"></div>
      <p>Coin booster gives +50% coin boost</p>
      <p>Crystal Boost (Crystals) = 1000</p>
      <button onclick="boostCrystals()">Crystal Boost</button>
      <div id="cboostError" style="color: red"></div>
      <p>Crystal booster gives +10% Cyrstals</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Tab4" class="tabcontent">
  <div>
  <h3>- Font Selector -</h3>
  <select id="font-selector">
    <p>
      - Fonts -
    </p>
    <option value="Arial, sans-serif">Arial</option>
    <option value="Comic Sans, serif">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Courier New, monospace">Courier New</option>
  </select>
   <p>
     <h3>
        - Color Picker -
    </h3>
    </p> <label for="color-picker">Choose a color:</label>
<input type="color" id="color-picker" name="color-picker">
<button id="apply-color">Apply color</button>

      <h3>- Site Usage -</h3>
  <p>Time Spent on Site: <span id="time-spent"></span></p>
  <p>Most Coins Earned: <span id="most-coins"></span></p>
</div>
    <h3>
      - MISC -
    </h3>
    <button id="reset-progress-btn">Reset Progress (NOT PRESTIGE)</button>

</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('font-selector').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedFont = this.value;
    document.body.style.fontFamily = selectedFont;
  });
</script>


<script>
  document.getElementById('font-selector').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedFont = this.value;
    document.body.style.fontFamily = selectedFont;
  });
</script>

    <div id="Tab5" class="tabcontent">
      <p>No Page Found :/</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>V.0.0.5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="credits-box">
      <h2>Credits</h2>
      <p>
        Heifest, Lead Developer | RisingPhoneix, Co-Developer | Bxx Duck,
        Manager
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried using local data and it just would break anytime I tried it. So I'm attempting cookies.

Comment: There is nothing to get because it was never set. You need to use `localStorage.setItem()` at some point, how else is `getItem()` supposed to get anything else then `null`

Comment: So at the end of the javascript just pud `localStorage.setItem(minerGameData) or am I supposed to do something else?

Comment: I don't know where you should put it - depends on how you want your save function to function. But wihtout "saving" there is no "loading". So at some point you need to save (use setItem())